# Why do I different values compared to my theoretical time?

Tags: time, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I'm having an experience about time needed to charge the capacitor to the 63.2% voltage of the batteries. There are resistance, capacitor and batteries in the circuit.

When I calculate the theoretical time needed, I get a value which is different than what I get when i practically calculate it with my hand terminal. This is how it is supposed to be, I know that but what is the reason it is different. Why does it take longer to charge it in real life, what is the force excluded in theory that changes it?

Comment: Without knowing what "theory" you are using, it's hard to be able to comment on this. How do you measure the charge on the capacitor? Is there a leakage path you are not accounting for? Perhaps there is a stray capacitance? What is the setup you are using for measurement?

Comment: t = RC is the formula.

Comment: It's true that the time constant for the RC circuit is $\tau = RC$ but I don't understand what you mean by "practically calculate it with my hand terminal".  Please add additional details or an example practical calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know why *you* got a different answer in *your* calculation, but here are some general considerations.

Assume you have a circuit like this:

[image]

You would think that you can easily compute the time constant $\tau = R_1 C_1 = 10^{-4}s$.

However, it is most likely that your real circuit isn't actually like this.

First - capacitors are notoriously inaccurate: unless you have specific timing applications, this is usually not a problem. Tolerances of 20% are not uncommon (see http://www.robotoid.com/appnotes/electronics-capacitor-markings.html for a summary of markings: see if you can figure out what your capacitor's tolerance is). It is usually marked lower than you need - for decoupling purposes you would rather have an error on the high side. This would make the observed time higher than calculated.

Second - your measurement setup can affect the result. For example, if your series resistor $R_1$ is large compared to the impedance of the scope you use for the measurement (1 MOhm for each would be possible) then your *effective* impedance for the circuit is only 500k - half of what you thought. This would make the observed time lower than the value calculated.

Third - if your capacitor is quite small, it is possible that parasitic capacitance plays a role. This would be important when you are working with pF capacitors. It would make the observed value higher.

Fourth - it is possible that your voltage source (or the switching element you use with it) has high internal impedance, making the effective resistance larger than you thought.

Finally - it is conceivable that your time scale is not calibrated correctly. On analog scopes, it is possible to vary the X (time) axis gain continuously in order to align signals with specific lines on the graticule; make sure your scale is locked / calibrated before taking a measurement.

The above is not an exhaustive list: but without more information about your experiment, I can only describe some "typical" errors. My guess is that your capacitor is bigger than you think.